# Stuck with Google Sheet formula

Tags: arrays, date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm stuck!! Please help me with the following:

Mm/dd/yyyy
01/01/2020

In this date, I can extract the month by
=Month(01/01/2020)
I will get = January

In this date, I can extract the year by
=Year(01/01/2020)
I will get = 2020

But my requirement is I want to extract month and year together from same date and year in a single formula.

Ie, January 2020

What formula should I use?

---

Comment: Did you try the [concatenate](https://www.lifewire.com/concatenate-text-data-in-google-spreadsheets-3123801) function?

Comment: Are you using the month and year for additional calculations or do you just want it to display in this format? If the latter, you can define a custom date-time formatting for the cell values in format/number/more formats

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=TEXT(A2; "mmmm yyyy")
```

[image]

for arrayformula use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="";;TEXT(A2:A; "mmmm yyyy")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Player0, I should have been more precise with my requirement. I want to use this as one of the criterion for a criteria range inside the sumifs.

Following is the formula

=sumifs(Projects!$E:$E, ArrayFormula(MONTH(Projects!$K:$K)),"<="&TEXT(C1,"MM YY"),Projects!$C:$C,"Mo Farazi")

Please let me know if this will work, else give me a work around how should I define the criterion to match with only the month and year.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Please also add this changes to the original question, so others will have a better idea.